# Alignment plugin in Sublime Text does not work with style.less (less file)

Tags: css, alignment, less, sublimetext

As the title, i can't find the way to make alignment plugin available with .less file. It's just work on CSS File

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this yet, but I have a pretty strong hunch that it might help your case.

Open sublime text, and go to Preferences>Browse Packages

Look for the Alignment plugin folder and enter in it.

Look at the files in there, you will see:

- Base File.sublime-settings
- CSS.sublime-settings
- Javascript.sublime-settings
- JSON.sublime-settings

Try your hand at creating a `LESS.sublime-settings` file in there, copying the contents of another of the settings files, for example, the JSON.sublime-settings contains this:

> {     "alignment_chars": ["=", ":"] }

It seems to me, that to enable alignment to work as expected with other filetypes not designed as default with the plugin, one would have to add this settings file to the plugin in order for it to work out.

I am not sure if the file name has to be case sensitive towards the syntax you want align to work with. If you installed the less package, you should see "LESS" shows up in the list as all caps, this is why my guess is to name the file `LESS.sublime-settings`. You can try different naming if it doesn't go at first...

Answer (score 3):

Open any LESS file in Sublime Text.

Navigate to:

```
- Preferences
-- Package Settings
--- Alignment
---- Settings-Syntax Specific-User
```

Alternatively, if you're on a Mac hit `Command+Shift+P` and start typing 'Alignment' and the option will appear. Once clicked, an empty JSON file will be generated for you: `LESS.sublime-settings`

As EffectiX mentioned, just type in `{ "alignment_chars": [":"] }` or whatever you want to align on. Save the file. This will work with pretty much any file format if configured correctly.

Comment: just `":"` should be enough there (`=` never appears in Less or CSS statements you'd want to align).